# How to know catch Back Button or Forward Button events in single page application

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, backbone.js

Im working on a single page application which uses ASP.NET MVC, Backbone.js, and Jquery. I want to catch browser back button and forward button events for the bread crumb implementation.

I tried with hashchange event but hashchange fires always when a new hash value is put in url irrespective of the fact if it is refresh, back ,forward , or simple ajax call. Can you suggest me how to track back or forward button events?

Comment: are you using a backbone router? if so, then you can take advantage of pushState and listen for 'route' events in your router

Comment: yes Im using Backbone router. ok I'll try this

Answer (score 0):

For back button capturing i would suggest you can use Backbone.history method

```
Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true })
```